# issues matching number in string with boost regex

Tags: regex, boost, numbers

I'm trying to determine whether or not a string contains a number. This doesn't seem to be working.

```
static const regex re("([0-9]+)");
cout << regex_match("L5", re);
```

prints

```
0
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [boost docs on regex_match](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_match.html):

> Note that the result is true only if
>   the expression matches the whole of
>   the input sequence. If you want to
>   search for an expression somewhere
>   within the sequence then use
>   regex_search.

Comment: gah. I knew it was something really fundamental that I was missing. Thanks.